# Approximation of the identity in J. Muscat Functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

I have an issue with a proof in J. Muscat's Functional analysis book (prop. 9.21 on approximation of the identity). The author asserts that $h_n \ast g \to g$ in $C(\Bbb R)$ under the following conditions about the $(h_n)$ :
$\forall n \in \Bbb N,  h_n \in C(\Bbb R), \ge 0, \int h_n =1 $ and  $h_n \to 0$ uniformly on $\Bbb R \setminus [-\delta,\delta],  \forall \delta \gt 0$.

The proof uses a comparison which I believe is not valid. It says that for $g$ and $x$ fixed, given $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta(\epsilon)$ and a $N(\delta,\epsilon)$ such that $\forall n \ge N, 0 \le h_n(y) \le \epsilon $ (see extract of the proof below). Then the author considers the term  $\int_{\Bbb R \setminus [-\delta,\delta]} h_n(y)\lvert{g(x-y) - g(x)}\rvert dy \le \int_{\Bbb R \setminus [-\delta,\delta]} 2\epsilon \lVert g \rVert_C dy$ and goes on by $\le 2\epsilon \lVert g \rVert_C $. That last seems obviously not valid.

I think the issue with the proof is that we have no certainty about the behavior of $\int_{\Bbb R \setminus [-\delta,\delta]} h_n(y)dy$. I looked into other books some proofs about approximation of the identity, and I noticed that the assumptions on $(h_n)$ generally include the convergence $\forall \delta, \lim_{n\to \infty}  \int_{\Bbb R \setminus [-\delta,\delta]} h_n(y)dy = 0$. And I think this is the missing assumption in J. Muscat's proposition.

What do you think ?

[Proposition and proof in the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D29tz.png)

Comment: The proof looks wrong to me on several counts. If $g$ is just continuous it is not even clear as to what $\|g\|_C$ is. Your point is also correct.

Comment: In the book, it is defined as the set of real-valued bounded continuous functions.